# Why does atomic_flag.clear() have a sub-optimal default memory_order argument?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

`std::atomic_flag` has 2 functions with these default `std::memory_order`s:

```
void clear(std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst);
bool test_and_set(std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

Perhaps I'm wrong, but shouldn't `clear` *always* be `memory_order_release` and `test_and_set` *always* be `memory_order_acquire`? Maybe I misunderstand what these do.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `memory_order_release` and `memory_order_acquire` mean.  They are about memory order, not locking.  (Although defining the memory order is important for _implementing_ locks.)  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order.  `clear()` could be `memory_order_release` but `test_and_set` could _never_ be `memory_order_acquire`, since it is a read-modify-write it would have to be `memory_order_acq_release`.  There are a few architectures where you can get small performance gains using something other than `memory_order_seq_cst`, but usually not worth it.

Comment: @WanderingLogic You only need the minimum ordering (acquire and release) to implement locks.

Comment: "_but shouldn't clear always be memory_order_release and test_and_set always be memory_order_acquire?_" It isn't clear why you expect that. A stronger memory ordering does not hurt (well it should not hurt even though some ppl claimed it might due to faulty spec).

Answer (score 4):

The default memory order is sequential consistency (`std::memory_order_seq_cst`) for all atomic operations in c++11.  You can specify a more relaxed memory order if you want, although that is often more complicated to reason about.

The `std::atomic_flag` is garanteeded to be lock-free and can be used to build other synchronization methods.  Whereas `std::atomic<T>` types can be implemented with locks if the compiler/library writer so chooses and still conform to the specification.  So this is why `std::atomic_flag` exists with these defaults.  Depending on what you are trying to do it might make sense to specify a different memory order but the defaults are set to be conservatively correct with sequential consistency.